# Change username without root access?

Tags: ssh, root

I've learned to ssh for the first time, and am logged into my university mainframe account. Can I change my username without root? Or is it like a password where I need root?

Answer (score 4):

Your username is determined by the system administrator when the account is created.  You pretty much need `root` level privileges to change it.

Your password is not fixed and can be changed with the `passwd` command.  You need to know the old password to change it, and the system *may* have restrictions (e.g. can not change more than once a day).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need root access to change your username if the system uses passwd files for authentication. However, most likely the access at your site is controlled by means of `LDAP` or `YP` or other centralized account management services

You need not `root` access to change your password as soon as you know your password and `passwd` utility is available to you.

Comment: being able to change your password with `passwd` assumes that it isn't a poorly configured LDAP setup (you can configure LDAP without giving users write permissions to their own passwords). Normally a reasonable assumption, but not a guarantee. The admin could also disable `passwd` but that's a bit more deliberate and counterproductive.